# App Design in Django

Tags: django, algorithm, django-models, django-views

I have a general algorithm design question. I am creating a Django app that will connect to an API, but I won't be storing these results (at least not at first). After I retrieve the data from the API I manipulate it accordingly and have already created a class with numerous methods to do this.

Should the programming logic for this be performed in the model or the view for the Django framework? Is one more sustainable than the other (e.g. in a few months I decide to store the information). Also, is it best to encapsulate my class in its own file, and them import into the model/view?

Thanks!
Rob

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to store data, don't use Djnago's built in models.

Write views and import your own modules/classes.

Bonus: If your views share a lot of logic (probably related to request/response handling), use class based views and write a common MyBaseView.